# How to select random element from a list in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I forgot how to pick a random color from the list that I made of the colors. Here's the code I have right now.

```
from turtle import *
from random import *

speed(0)
bgcolor=('black')
colors=('purple', 'teal', 'blue', 'magenta', 'lilac', 'cyan')
for i in range(15):
    draw:(circle)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using **random.choice()** also should be considered

```
import random

colors = ('purple', 'teal', 'blue', 'magenta', 'lilac', 'cyan')
selected_color = random.choice(colors)
```

**Result**

```
selected_color
# 'cyan'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
colour = colors[random.randint(0, len(colours)-1)]
```

This will pick a random item from your list

Comment: It's a lot simpler to use the function `random.choice`.